# How to "delete" every element in array by value in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have been trying to solve this problem for about 5 days..can't find any solution please send help. I am supposed to implement a function to "delete" every element in an array by value. Let's say my array is "Hello" and I want to delete every "l". So far I can only delete l once. By the way keep in mind I am not allowed to use pointers for this function...(we haven't learned that yet in my school) Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strdel(char array[], char c);

int main(void)
{
    char source[40];
    printf("\nStrdel test: ");
    strcpy(source, "Hello");
    printf("\nsource = %s", source);
    strdel(source, 'l');
    printf("\nStrdel: new source = %s", source);
    return 0;
}

void strdel(char array[], char c)
{
    int string_lenght;
    int i;
    for (string_lenght = 0; array[string_lenght] != '\0'; string_lenght++) {} 

    for (i = 0; i < string_lenght; i++) {
        if (array[i] == c) {
            for (i = i; array[i] != '\0'; ++i)
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `strlen()` to calculate length?

Comment: Tip - use a 'read' index and a 'write' index. Start them the same and increment each as necessary...

Comment: don't use the same variable `i` in different for loops

Comment: i'm not allowed to use other functions to implement strdel that's why i don't use strlen... I can only write them in main to test if my function is correct

Comment: `i = i;` was your clue that things weren't right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple use 2 indexes, one for reading and one for writing.  [@Carl Norum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487477/how-to-delete-every-element-in-array-by-value-in-c/53487767#comment93844742_53487477)

```
void strdel(char array[], char c) {
  int read_index = 0;
  int write_index = 0;
  while (array[read_index] != '\0') {
    if (array[read_index] != c) {
      array[write_index] = array[read_index];
      write_index++;  // Only advance write_index when a character is copied
    }
    read_index++;     // Always advance read_index
  }
  array[write_index] = '\0';
}
```

The has O(n) performance, much faster than using nested `for()` loops which is O(n*n).

---

Details:

> OP: By the way keep in mind I am not allowed to use pointers for this function.

Note that `array` in `void strdel(char array[], char c)` is a pointer, even though it might look like an array.

`int` for array indexing is OK for learner and much code, yet better to use `size_t`.  `int` may lack the range needed.  Type `size_t` is an unsigned type that is neither too narrow nor too wide for array indexing needs.  This becomes important for very long *strings*.

Comment: The `while(array[read_index])` may be confusing for a new programmer - I'd suggest explaining that when it's null, that statement will fail (or even using a for loop in the example and explaining how it can be compressed to a while - that way the comparison is still visible)

Comment: @BrydonGibson Amended `while (array[read_index])` to `while (array[read_index] != '\0')` which is functionally equivalent.

Comment: No idea what while(array[read_index]) does. How does that work ? the rest is somewhat clear

Comment: @Saty `while (test_condition)`  tests if `test_condition != 0`.

Comment: I've tested your code and for my array: "Hello" and "l" I only get ll instead of Heo ? Why is that ? I'm still trying to understand why you use only 1 while loop

Comment: @Saty Only one loop is needed.  Rather than shift the remaining part of the _string_ by 1 and do so potential many times, as you did, this code copies desired  character once.  (Note code changed from `==` to `!=`.)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is related to using the variable `i` in both loops. So once the inner loop is executed, outer loop will terminate right after.

Use another variable for the inner loop.

```
void strdel(char array[], char c)
{
    int string_lenght;
    int i, j;
    for (string_lenght = 0; array[string_lenght] != '\0'; string_lenght++) {} 

    for (i = 0; i < string_lenght; i++) {
        if (array[i] == c) {
            for (j = i; array[j] != '\0'; ++j)  // Use variable j instead of i
                array[j] = array[j + 1];

           --i;              // Decrement i to "stay" at the same index
           --string_lenght;  // As one character were just removed
        }
    }
}
```

The above shows how to make OPs approach work. For a better solution see the answer from @chux : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53487767/4386427

Comment: Thanks so much ! I used read_index and write_index for i and j so that it's a bit clearer.... Could you please explain why you need to use --i after the second for loop ? That was the key step that i was always missing...

Comment: @Saty The `--i` is needed to stay at the same index in the next loop. In other words - it cancels the `++i` in the `for` statement